# OpenOffice converter don't work with apache

Tags: php, apache, pdf, openoffice.org

Does anyone know why this works great with phpCLI but fails with apache?

```
$cmd = "soffice --headless --nofirststartwizard -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export file.doc -outdir converted/";
exec($cmd, $dump, $ret);
```

Comment: Make sure the files you want to access can be accessed by Apache, or whatever user php uses.

Comment: Log errors from command: `$cmd = "soffice --headless --nofirststartwizard -convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export file.doc -outdir converted/ 2>/tmp/convert-errors.log";` and check errors output after command executed.

Comment: Error log is empty ;/
for tests I gave 777 rights to soffice

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this few more hours, but finally I've found solution here
http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2011/11/19/converting-.docx-to-pdf-or-.doc-to-pdf-or-.doc.aspx

I hope this can help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Try use "export HOME=/tmp" before run OpenOffice.

Example:

```
  export HOME=/tmp
  soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir /var/www/public/uploads/ /var/www/public/uploads/artcl.ppt
```